# Using Match with Multiple Clauses Causes Odd Results

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am writing a Cypher query in Neo4j 2.0.4 that attempts to get the total number of inbound and outbound relationships for a selected node. I can do this easily when I only use this query one-node-at-a-time, like so:

```
MATCH (g1:someIndex{name:"name1"})
MATCH g1-[r1]-()
RETURN count(r1);
//Returns 305

MATCH (g2:someIndex{name:"name2"})
MATCH g2-[r2]-()
RETURN count(r2);
//Returns 2334
```

But when I try to run the query with 2 nodes together (i.e. get the total number of relationships for both g1 and g2), I seem to get a *bizarre* result.

```
MATCH (g1:someIndex{name:"name1"}), (g2:someIndex{name:"name2"})
MATCH g1-[r1]-(), g2-[r2]-()
RETURN count(r1)+count(r2);
//Returns 1423740
```

For some reason, the number is much much greater than the total of 305+2334.

It seems like other Neo4j users have run into strange issues when using multiple `MATCH` clauses, so I read through Michael Hunger's explanation at https://groups.google.com/d/msg/neo4j/7ePLU8y93h8/8jpuopsFEFsJ, which advised Neo4j users to pipe the results of one match using `WITH` to avoid "identifier uniqueness". However, when I run the following query, it simply times out:

```
MATCH (g1:gene{name:"SV422_HUMAN"}),(g2:gene{name:"BRCA1_HUMAN"})
MATCH g1-[r1]-()
WITH r1
MATCH g2-[r2]-()
RETURN count(r1)+count(r2);
```

I suspect this query doesn't return because there's a lot of records returned by `r1`. In this case, how would I operate my "get-number-of-relationships" query on 2 nodes? Am I just using some incorrect syntax, or is there some fundamental issue with the logic of my "2 node at a time" query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first problem is that you are returning a Cartesian product when you do this:

```
MATCH (g1:someIndex{name:"name1"}), (g2:someIndex{name:"name2"})
MATCH g1-[r1]-(), g2-[r2]-()
RETURN count(r1)+count(r2);
```

If there are 305 instances of `r1` and 2334 instances of `r2`, you're returning (305 * 2334) == 711870 rows, and because you are summing this (`count(r1)+count(r2)`) you're getting a total of 711870 + 711870 == 1423740.

Your second problem is that you are not carrying over `g2` in the `WITH` clause of this query:

```
MATCH (g1:gene{name:"SV422_HUMAN"}),(g2:gene{name:"BRCA1_HUMAN"})
MATCH g1-[r1]-()
WITH r1
MATCH g2-[r2]-()
RETURN count(r1)+count(r2);
```

You match on `g2` in the first `MATCH` clause, but then you leave it behind when you only carry over `r1` in the `WITH` clause at line 3. Then, in line 4, when you match on `g2-[r2]-()` you are matching literally everything in your graph, because `g2` has been unbound.

Let me walk through a solution with the movie dataset that ships with the Neo4j browser, as you have not provided sample data. Let's say I want to get the total count of relationships attached to Tom Hanks and Hugo Weaving.

As separate queries:

```
MATCH (:Person {name:'Tom Hanks'})-[r]-()
RETURN COUNT(r)
```

=> 13

```
MATCH (:Person {name:'Hugo Weaving'})-[r]-()
RETURN COUNT(r)
```

=> 5

If I try to do it your way, I'll get (13 * 5) * 2 == 90, which is incorrect:

```
MATCH (:Person {name:'Tom Hanks'})-[r1]-(), 
      (:Person {name:'Hugo Weaving'})-[r2]-()
RETURN COUNT(r1) + COUNT(r2)
```

=> 90

Again, this is because I've matched on all combinations of `r1` and `r2`, of which there are 65 (13 * 5 == 65) and then summed this to arrive at a total of 90 (65 + 65 == 90).

The solution is to use `DISTINCT`:

```
MATCH (:Person {name:'Tom Hanks'})-[r1]-(), 
      (:Person {name:'Hugo Weaving'})-[r2]-()
RETURN COUNT(DISTINCT r1) + COUNT(DISTINCT r2)
```

=> 18

Clearly, the `DISTINCT` modifier only counts the distinct instances of each entity.

You can also accomplish this with `WITH` if you wanted:

```
MATCH (:Person {name:'Tom Hanks'})-[r]-()
WITH COUNT(r) AS r1
MATCH (:Person {name:'Hugo Weaving'})-[r]-()
RETURN r1 + COUNT(r)
```

=> 18

TL;DR - Beware of Cartesian products. `DISTINCT` is your friend:

```
MATCH (:someIndex{name:"name1"})-[r1]-(), 
      (:someIndex{name:"name2"})-[r2]-()
RETURN COUNT(DISTINCT r1) + COUNT(DISTINCT r2);
```

Comment: Thank you Nicole! I had no clue that my current query was using a cross product; that makes a lot more sense now.

Answer (score 3):

The explosion of results you're seeing can be easily explained:

```
MATCH (g1:someIndex{name:"name1"}), (g2:someIndex{name:"name2"})
MATCH g1-[r1]-(), g2-[r2]-()
RETURN count(r1)+count(r2);
//Returns 1423740
```

In the 2nd line every combination of any relationship from `g1` is combined with any relationship of `g2`, this explains the number since 1423740 = 305 * 2334 * 2. So you're evaluating basically a cross product here.

The right way to calculate the sum of all relationships for `name1` and `name2` is:

```
MATCH (g:someIndex)-[r]-()
WHERE g.name in ["name1", "name2"]
RETURN count(r)
```

Comment: Thank you Stefan! This makes sense now.  +1